# Getting CS1513 } expected but I think that my code is valid

Tags: c#, linqpad

I am rather experienced with C# however, sometimes, I need a little help from the community.  This is one of those times.

I am using [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net), which is a wonderful tool, and I highly suggest you go out and download it if you have not already.

With that out of the way, I need to figure out why LINQPad is throwing a compiler error `CS1513 } expected`.  It does not tell me what the offending line is, it just complains at me and then gives up, when I go to execute my script by pressing `F5`.

The issue is, I've checked my code from stem to stern and I can't find any obvious places where I forgot a closing brace.  I even poured this code into a temporary console app project inside Visual Studio and Visual Studio compiles it just fine.

[image: Figure 1. LINQPad reporting the CS1513 error.]

```
public const string CSHARP_PROJECT_FILE_PATTERN = "*.csproj";
public static string LATEST_POSTSHARP_VERSION { get; } = LINQPad.Actions.PostSharp.Get.PostSharpCurrentVersion();
//static readonly string LATEST_LOG4NET_VERSION = LINQPad.Actions.NuGet.Gallery.Get.LatestNuGetPackageVersionFromGallery("log4net");
public const string PACKAGES_CONFIG_FILE_NAME = "packages.config";
public const string PACKAGES_FOLDER_NAME = "packages";
public static readonly string STARTING_DIRECTORY = Path.Combine(
    LINQPad.Actions.Common.Get.UserProfileFolderPath(), @"source\repos\astrohart"
);
public const string STARTS_WITH_POSTSHARP_PATTERN = "PostSharp*";

public static string WorkingDirectory { get; set; }

public static readonly List<string> APPROVED_PACKAGE_LIST = new List<string> {
    "log4net",
    "PostSharp",
    "PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics",
    "PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics.Log4Net"
};

void Main()
{
    Proceed(STARTING_DIRECTORY);
}

void Proceed(string startingFolder)
{
    WorkingDirectory = startingFolder;

    Console.WriteLine($"Processing operations in folder '{startingFolder}'...");

    if (!Does.DirectoryExist(startingFolder)) return;
    if (!Does.FolderContainAtLeastOneSolution(startingFolder))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: The folder '{startingFolder}' does not contain any Visual Studio solutions.  Run this script in a folder that contains at least one solution (*.sln) file.");
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Checking whether the folder '{startingFolder}' contains at least one local Git repo...");

    if (Does.FolderContainAtLeastOneLocalGitRepo(
            startingFolder
        )
    )
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"At least one local Git repo was found in the folder '{startingFolder}' or its subfolders.");

        Configure.Git();
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Clearing the NuGet package cache...");

    /*
     * Clear the NuGet package cache.
     */

    Delete.AllSubFoldersOf(
        Path.Combine(
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86),
            @"Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages"
        )
    );

    Remove.ObsoletePostSharpPackageFoldersIn(startingFolder);

    var solutionFolders = Directory.EnumerateFiles(
            startingFolder,
            "*.sln",
            SearchOption.AllDirectories
        )
        .Select(Path.GetDirectoryName)
        .ToList();
    if (solutionFolders == null || !solutionFolders.Any()) return;

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("*** Updating the NuGet CLI executable and clearing the local cache ***");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Run.SystemCommand("nuget update -self", startingFolder, true);
    Run.SystemCommand("nuget locals all -clear", startingFolder, true);

    foreach (var solutionFolder in solutionFolders)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"Processing solution folder '{solutionFolder}'...");

        if (!Does.FolderExist(solutionFolder)) continue;
        //if (Does.FolderExist(Path.Combine(solutionFolder, PACKAGES_FOLDER_NAME))) continue; // already did this solution

        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(solutionFolder);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"*** Updating PostSharp to version {LATEST_POSTSHARP_VERSION} in projects and packages.config... ***");
        Console.WriteLine();

        if (Does.FolderContainAtLeastOneLocalGitRepo(solutionFolder))
            Pull.FromGitHub(
                solutionFolder
            );  // get latest changes

        Update.CSharpProjectFilesIn(
            solutionFolder
        );
        Update.PackageConfigFilesIn(
            solutionFolder
        );

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"*** Restoring NuGet packages in solution '{solutionFolder}.sln' ***");
        Console.WriteLine();

        Run.SystemCommand($"nuget restore -PackagesDirectory packages -Verbosity detailed -NoCache -DirectDownload -Source \"https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json\" -ConfigFile \"{Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%APPDATA%\NuGet\nuget.config")}\"", solutionFolder, true);

        //      Console.WriteLine();
        //      Console.WriteLine($"*** Updating NuGet packages in solution '{Path.GetFileName(solutionFolder)}.sln' ***");
        //      Console.WriteLine();
        //
        //      Run.SystemCommand($@"nuget update {Path.GetFileName(solutionFolder)}.sln -Source ""https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"" -Id log4net,PostSharp,PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics,PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics.Log4Net -RepositoryPath packages -DependencyVersion Lowest -Verbosity detailed -FileConflictAction Overwrite -ConfigFile ""{Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%APPDATA%\NuGet\nuget.config")}""", solutionFolder, true);

        Install.NuGetPackages(
            solutionFolder,
            APPROVED_PACKAGE_LIST
        );

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"*** Removing all prior versions of PostSharp from the 'packages' folder... ***");
        Console.WriteLine();

        Remove.ObsoletePostSharpPackageFoldersIn(
            solutionFolder
        );

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"*** Committing and pushing changes to source control... ***");
        Console.WriteLine();

        /*
         * Everything past this point is only doable if, and only if,
         * the current solution's folder contains a local Git repository.
         */

        if (!Does.FolderContainAtLeastOneLocalGitRepo(solutionFolder)) continue;

        Commit.ToGit(
            solutionFolder,
            "Update PostSharp"
        );

        Pull.FromGitHub(
            solutionFolder
        );

        Push.ToGitHub(
            solutionFolder
        );
    }

    /*
     * For some bizarre reason that I can't possibly even begin
     * to fathom, nuget CLI loves to install the prior version(s)
     * of PostSharp (to the \packages folder, anyway) alongside the
     * current version.  So, let's go into the \packages folder and
     * remove all folders from versions of PostSharp that do not 
     * correspond to the 'official' version.
     */


    Console.WriteLine("*** DONE ***");
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static class Commit
{
    public static void ToGit(string folder, string message, bool visible = true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Committing changes to local repository...");

        Run.SystemCommand($"git add .", folder, visible);
        Run.SystemCommand($"git commit -m \"{message}\"", folder, visible);
    }
}

public static class Configure
{
    public static void Git()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Configuring Git...");

        Run.SystemCommand("git config --global user.email \"brian.hart@xylogix.net\" --replace-all", UserQuery.WorkingDirectory, visible: true);
        Run.SystemCommand("git config --global user.name \"Brian Hart\" --replace-all", UserQuery.WorkingDirectory, visible: true);
        Run.SystemCommand("git config --global credential.helper wincred", UserQuery.WorkingDirectory, visible: true);
    }
}

public static class Delete
{
    public static void AllSubFoldersOf(string pathname, Func<string, bool> predicate)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Does.FolderExist(pathname)) return;

            var subFolders = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(
                pathname,
                "*",
                SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly
            )
            .Where(predicate)
            .ToList();
            if (subFolders == null || !subFolders.Any()) return;    // no folders found matching the search

            foreach (var subFolder in subFolders)
            {
                if (!Does.FolderExist(subFolder)) continue;

                LINQPad.Actions.Common.Delete.FolderIfExists(
                    subFolder
                );
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    public static void AllSubFoldersOf(string pathname)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Does.FolderExist(pathname)) return;

            var subFolders = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(
                pathname,
                "*",
                SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly
            )
            .ToList();
            if (subFolders == null || !subFolders.Any()) return;

            foreach (var subFolder in subFolders)
            {
                if (!Does.FolderExist(subFolder)) continue;

                LINQPad.Actions.Common.Delete.FolderIfExists(
                    subFolder
                );
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

public static class Does
{
    public static bool DirectoryExist(string pathname)
    {
        var result = false;

        try
        {
            result = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(
                pathname
            )
            && Directory.Exists(
                pathname
            );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {ex.Message}");

            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static bool FileExist(string pathname)
    {
        var result = false;

        try
        {
            result = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(
                pathname
            )
            && File.Exists(
                pathname
            );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {ex.Message}");

            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static bool FolderExist(string pathname)
        => DirectoryExist(pathname);

    public static bool FolderContainAtLeastOneSolution(string pathname)
    {
        var result = false;

        if (!DirectoryExist(pathname)) return result;

        try
        {
            result = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(
                        pathname,
                        "*",
                        SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly
                    )
                    .SelectMany(subdir =>
                        Directory.EnumerateFiles(
                                    subdir,
                                    "*.sln",
                                    SearchOption.AllDirectories
                                )
                    )
                    .Any();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);

            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static bool FolderContainAtLeastOneLocalGitRepo(string pathname)
    {
        var result = false;

        if (!DirectoryExist(pathname)) return result;

        try
        {
            result = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(
                pathname,
                ".git",
                SearchOption.AllDirectories
            )
            .Any();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);

            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static bool FolderContainPriorVersionOfPostSharp(string pathname)
    {
        var result = false;

        try
        {
            if (!Does.FolderExist(pathname)) return result;
            if (!Get.ParentFolderOf(pathname).EndsWith(PACKAGES_FOLDER_NAME))

                result =
                    Get.FolderName(pathname).StartsWith("PostSharp")
                    && !pathname.Contains(LATEST_POSTSHARP_VERSION);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {ex.Message}");

            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public static class Formulate
{
    public static string NuGetPackageInstallationLine(string solutionFolder, string packagesConfigFileOrPackageId)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            if (!Does.DirectoryExist(solutionFolder)) return result;
            if (Is.PathnameOfAPackagesConfigFile(packagesConfigFileOrPackageId)
                && !Does.FileExist(packagesConfigFileOrPackageId)) return result;

            result = $@"nuget install {(Is.PathnameOfAPackagesConfigFile(packagesConfigFileOrPackageId) ? Path.GetFileName(packagesConfigFileOrPackageId) : packagesConfigFileOrPackageId)} -Source ""https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"" -ConfigFile ""%APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config"" -DependencyVersion Highest -DirectDownload -NoCache -OutputDirectory packages -SolutionDirectory ""{solutionFolder}"" -Verbosity detailed";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {ex.Message}");

            result = string.Empty;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static string NuGetPackageInstallationLine(string solutionFolder, string packagesConfigFile, string approvedPackage)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            if (!Does.DirectoryExist(solutionFolder)) return result;
            if (!Does.FileExist(packagesConfigFile)) return result;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(approvedPackage)) return result;

            result = $@"nuget install {Path.GetFileName(packagesConfigFile)} -Source ""https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"" -ConfigFile ""%APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config"" -DependencyVersion Lowest -DirectDownload -NoCache -OutputDirectory packages -SolutionDirectory ""{solutionFolder}"" -Verbosity detailed";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {ex.Message}");

            result = string.Empty;
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public static class Get
{
    public static IList<string> CSharpProjectFilePathsInFolder(string pathname)
    {
        var result = Enumerable.Empty<string>().ToList();

        try
        {
            if (!Does.DirectoryExist(pathname)) return result;

            result = LINQPad.Actions.Common.Get.FilesInAllSubFolders(
                pathname, CSHARP_PROJECT_FILE_PATTERN
            )
            .ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {ex.Message}");

            result = Enumerable.Empty<string>().ToList();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static string FolderName(string pathname)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            if (!Does.DirectoryExist(pathname)) return result;

            result = Path.GetFileName(
                pathname
            );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {ex.Message}");

            result = string.Empty;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static IList<string> PackageConfigFilePathsInFolder(string pathname)
    {
        var result = Enumerable.Empty<string>().ToList();

        try
        {
            if (!Does.DirectoryExist(pathname)) return result;

            result = LINQPad.Actions.Common.Get.FilesInAllSubFolders(
                pathname, PACKAGES_CONFIG_FILE_NAME
            )
            .ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {ex.Message}");

            result = Enumerable.Empty<string>().ToList();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static string PackagesFolderPathnameFrom(string pathname)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            if (!Does.DirectoryExist(pathname)) return result;
            if (!Does.FileExist(
                    Path.Combine(
                        pathname,
                        $"{Get.FolderName(pathname)}.sln"
                    )
                )
            ) return result;

            result = Path.Combine(
                pathname,
                PACKAGES_FOLDER_NAME
            );

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {ex.Message}");

            result = string.Empty;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static string ParentFolderOf(string pathname)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            if (!Does.DirectoryExist(pathname)) return result;

            result = Path.GetDirectoryName(
                pathname
            );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {ex.Message}");

            result = string.Empty;
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public static class Install
{
    public static void NuGetPackages(string solutionFolder)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Does.DirectoryExist(solutionFolder)) return;

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"*** Installing NuGet packages in solution ***");
            Console.WriteLine();

            foreach (var packagesConfigFile in Get.PackageConfigFilePathsInFolder(
                    solutionFolder
                )
            )
            {
                if (!Does.FileExist(packagesConfigFile)) continue;

                Run.SystemCommand(
                    Formulate.NuGetPackageInstallationLine(
                        solutionFolder,
                        packagesConfigFile
                    ),
                    solutionFolder,
                    true
                );
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    public static void NuGetPackages(string solutionFolder, IEnumerable<string> approvedPackageList)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Does.DirectoryExist(solutionFolder)) return;

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"*** Installing NuGet packages in solution ***");
            Console.WriteLine();

            if (approvedPackageList == null || !approvedPackageList.Any()) return;

            foreach (var approvedPackage in approvedPackageList)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(approvedPackage)) continue;

                Run.SystemCommand(
                    Formulate.NuGetPackageInstallationLine(
                        solutionFolder,
                        approvedPackage
                    ),
                    solutionFolder,
                    true
                );
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

public static class Is
{
    public static bool PathnameOfAPackagesConfigFile(string pathname)
    {
        var result = false;

        try
        {
            result = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(
                pathname
            )
            && File.Exists(
                pathname
            )
            && PACKAGES_CONFIG_FILE_NAME.Equals(
                Path.GetFileName(
                    pathname
                )
            );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {ex.Message}");

            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public static class Pull
{
    public static void FromGitHub(string folder, bool visible = true)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(folder)) return;
        if (!Directory.Exists(folder)) return;

        Console.WriteLine("Pulling latest changes from remote...");

        Run.SystemCommand("git pull -v --no-rebase \"origin\"", folder, visible);
    }
}

public static class Push
{
    public static void ToGitHub(string folder, bool visible = true)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(folder)) return;
        if (!Directory.Exists(folder)) return;

        Console.WriteLine("Pushing changes to remote...");

        Run.SystemCommand("git push -u origin master", folder, true);
    }
}

public static class Remove
{
    public static void ObsoletePostSharpPackageFoldersIn(string folderContainingSolutions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Trying to remove old installed versions of PostSharp...");
        try
        {
            if (!Does.DirectoryExist(folderContainingSolutions)) return;

            var packagesFolders =
                Directory.EnumerateDirectories(
                    folderContainingSolutions,
                    "*",
                    SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly
                )
                .SelectMany(subdir =>
                    Directory.EnumerateDirectories(
                        subdir,
                        PACKAGES_FOLDER_NAME,
                        SearchOption.AllDirectories
                    )
                )
                .ToList();
            if (packagesFolders == null || !packagesFolders.Any()) return;

            foreach (var packagesFolder in packagesFolders)
            {
                if (!Does.DirectoryExist(packagesFolder)) continue;

                var postSharpPackageFolders = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(
                    packagesFolder,
                    STARTS_WITH_POSTSHARP_PATTERN,
                    SearchOption.AllDirectories
                )
                .ToList();
                if (postSharpPackageFolders == null || !postSharpPackageFolders.Any()) continue;

                foreach (var postSharpPackageFolder in postSharpPackageFolders)
                {
                    if (!Does.DirectoryExist(postSharpPackageFolder)) continue;
                    if (postSharpPackageFolder.Contains(LATEST_POSTSHARP_VERSION)) continue;

                    Console.WriteLine($"Deleting the folder '{postSharpPackageFolder}'...");

                    LINQPad.Actions.Common.Delete.FolderIfExists(
                       postSharpPackageFolder
                   );
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

public static class Update
{
    public static void CSharpProjectFilesIn(string solutionFolder)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Does.DirectoryExist(solutionFolder)) return;

            foreach (var cSharpProjectFile in Get.CSharpProjectFilePathsInFolder(
                    solutionFolder
                )
            )
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cSharpProjectFile)) continue;
                if (!File.Exists(cSharpProjectFile)) continue;

                Console.WriteLine($"Updating '{cSharpProjectFile}'...");

                var contents = LINQPad.Actions.Common.Get.FileContents(
                    cSharpProjectFile
                );
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contents)) continue;

                if (
                    contents.Contains("PostSharp")
                    && !contents.Contains(LATEST_POSTSHARP_VERSION)
                )
                {
                    contents = Update.PostSharpVersionToLatest(
                        contents
                    );

                    Save.FileContents(cSharpProjectFile, contents, Encoding.UTF8, backup: false);
                }

                break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    public static void PackageConfigFilesIn(string solutionFolder)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Does.DirectoryExist(solutionFolder)) return;

            foreach (var packagesConfigFile in Get.PackageConfigFilePathsInFolder(
                    solutionFolder
                )
            )
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(packagesConfigFile)) continue;
                if (!File.Exists(packagesConfigFile)) continue;

                Console.WriteLine($"Updating '{packagesConfigFile}'...");

                var contents = LINQPad.Actions.Common.Get.FileContents(
                    packagesConfigFile
                );
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contents)) continue;

                if (
                    contents.Contains("PostSharp")
                    && !contents.Contains(LATEST_POSTSHARP_VERSION)
                )
                {
                    contents = Update.PostSharpVersionToLatest(
                        contents
                    );

                    Save.FileContents(packagesConfigFile, contents, Encoding.UTF8);
                }

                break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    private static string PostSharpVersionToLatest(string contents)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contents)) return result;

        try
        {
            result =
                Regex.Replace(
                    contents,
                    @"6\.\d+\.\d+",
                    LATEST_POSTSHARP_VERSION
                );
            result =
                Regex.Replace(
                    result,
                    @"6\.\d+\.\d+\-rc",
                    LATEST_POSTSHARP_VERSION
                );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);

            result = string.Empty;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

**LIsting 1.** The code that LINQPad refuses to run.

Notes: This is a `.linq` file not a `.cs` file.  So therefore, `Main` does not have to be `static`.  Think of this code if it is in a class called `UserQuery` -- the class definition includes the entire listing above.

Can I please have another pair(s) of eyes to see if I am missing a closing brace somewhere, or have some other error?

BTW please use this code if you feel it is useful, in your own projects.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @TessellatingHacker's answer, I discovered I set the **Language** to `C# Statements` instead of `C# Program`.  I think it was a case of the `.linq` file getting corrupted or something because I am generally pretty good at making sure it's set to `C# Program` (my default language preference) by default.

[image]

Comment: There is a "Language" dropdown at the top of the LINQPad screen; With the default "C# Statements" then I get the "*CS1513 } expected*" error, but if I change it to "C# Program" then that goes away. I don't know how to reference the LINQPad.Actions namespace or others so I can't confirm that will help, but it might. (From deleting chunks of the code one method at a time, I can't isolate a single one which causes the problem to go away, which suggests it's not the code at fault).

Answer (score 0):

I feel kind of stupid posting this question.  I am grateful that kind people on this site such as @TessellatingHacker pointed out what was actually going on Such as the `C# Statements` option being selected in the drop-down at the top of LINQPad:

[image]

[image]

Thank you, @TessellatingHacker, got it.  I can close this question as solved now.